# Get the categories joined to a custom taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, taxonomy

I have a custom post of portfolio items. Within the custom post I have categories set up, as well as a custom taxonomy of clients. I am listing the portfolio items by client, but I need also need to filter these by which category they appear in. I have this so far:

```
$terms = get_terms('client');

if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
      echo "<ul>";
 foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
     $term_id = $term->term_id;


   echo '<li class="item"> '; 
        $taxonomy = 'category';
        $client_cats = get_terms($taxonomy);
        foreach ($client_cats as $client_cat) {
        echo '<li>' . $client_cat->name.'</a></li>';
        }
        if (function_exists('get_wp_term_image'))
        {
        $meta_image = get_wp_term_image($term_id);
        //It will give category/term image url
        }

        echo $meta_image; // category/term image url
   echo $term->name . "</li>";

 }
 echo "</ul>";

} else {
      echo "No posts";
}
```

But this gives me a list of the clients with a list of all the categories after each one. How can I filter the categories so that only the ones the client is linked to is displayed?

Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: I didn't quite get what you're asking, how do you relate the two taxonomies?

Comment: maybe get some clue from here https://gist.github.com/accrane/6334e078e9cc9b140de395f0f197c66d

Comment: They are related in that they are both for a custom post type - portfolio items, so I am only querying that post type. I am looking for items for each client taxonomy that has posts also within the category taxonomy